# How to add custom claims to Google ID_Token with Google OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, jwt, google-oauth

We have configured Google OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications as mentioned in https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#httprest.

1. Got the code using,

   https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?
   scope=https%3A//www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly&
   access_type=offline&
   include_granted_scopes=true&
   response_type=code&
   state=state_parameter_passthrough_value&
   redirect_uri=https%3A//oauth2.example.com/code&
   client_id=client_id.
2. Got JWT using,

   POST /token HTTP/1.1
   Host: oauth2.googleapis.com
   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

   code=4/P7q7W91a-oMsCeLvIaQm6bTrgtp7&
   client_id=your_client_id&
   client_secret=your_client_secret&
   redirect_uri=https%3A//oauth2.example.com/code&
   grant_type=authorization_code

Now my decoded id_token looks like,

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "b63ee0be093d9bc312d958c9966d21f0c8f6bbbb",
  "typ": "JWT"
}.{
  "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
  "azp": "640523414127-4eaptj129qb79v33pm0il71r4f506ts9.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "aud": "640523414127-4eaptj129qb79v33pm0il71r4f506ts9.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "sub": "118185565008542236388",
  "email": "mail_ID@gmail.com",
  "email_verified": true,
  "at_hash": "K_sS85PI2ptkOIrUoWcM7Q",
  "iat": 1595931406,
  "exp": 1595935006
}.[Signature]
```

Now how can I add custom claim so that the above id_token contains my new claim, for example,

"policy": "readWrite"

And finally the decoded id_token should look like,

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "b63ee0be093d9bc312d958c9966d21f0c8f6bbbb",
  "typ": "JWT"
}.{
  "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
  "azp": "640523414127-4eaptj129qb79v33pm0il71r4f506ts9.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "aud": "640523414127-4eaptj129qb79v33pm0il71r4f506ts9.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "sub": "118185565008542236388",
  "email": "mail_ID@gmail.com",
  "email_verified": true,
  "at_hash": "K_sS85PI2ptkOIrUoWcM7Q",
  "iat": 1595931406,
  "exp": 1595935006,
**"policy": "readWrite"**
}.[Signature]
```

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Apparently, Google is trying to sell it via Identity Platform, which does a bit different thing and requires coding in Admin SDK. There's an open ticket for that, but Google seem to ignore the demand: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/133774835

Alternatively, try using SAML(if your app supports it) => create Web Application (in cloud ADMIN console) and map custom attributes there.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe it will help:

> Configuring custom claims on users (...) Before you begin Install the
> Admin SDK. (...)
>
> ```
> admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, {admin: true})
> ```
>
> https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/how-to-configure-custom-claims

Comment: Sadly, identity platform is not identity.